# Передать данные из формы на одной странице в другую форму на другой странице в Tilda

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tilda

Есть сайт на Tilda. Сайт состоит из двух страниц.
Нужно передать номер телефона из формы (при отправке формы) на одной странице в другую форму на другой странице.
Пробовал различными способами. Через методы get/post, localstorage, sessionstorage и тд. Данные не поступают через ссылку, не отображаются в localstorage и sessionstorage. Возможно криво делал, не знаю, но при обычной верстке все работает, а в тильде - нет.
Был ли у кого такой опыт или знает кто как решить данную задачу?